# Filtering data out of a collection with specific string

Tags: kotlin

I would like to receive only data which does not contain some specific strings.

What I have is this code:

```
@GET
@Path("getParticipants")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
fun getParticipants(): Map<String, List<String>> {
    val (nodeInfo, nodeUpdates) = rpcOps.networkMapFeed()
    nodeUpdates.notUsed()
    return mapOf("getParticipants" to nodeInfo
            .map { it.legalIdentities.first().toString() }
            .filter { it != myLegalName && it !in NOTARY_NAMES })
}
```

While running this code above I recive this:

```
0   "C=GB,L=London,O=UserA"
1   "C=GB,L=London,O=Controller"
2   "C=US,L=New York,O=UserB"
```

- myLegalName is = "UserA"
- NOTARY_NAMES is = "Controller"

What I would like to achive is, that the getParticipants retrieves me only the rows which are NOT CONTAINING UserA ("myLegalName") and NOT CONTAINING Controller ("NOTARY_NAMES"), so in this case only "C=US,L=New York,O=UserB".

Comment: put filter before map

Comment: what is the type of `it` at the point of filter?

Comment: @Les its string

Comment: try `!it.contains(myLegalName) && !it.contains(NOTARY_NAMES)`

Comment: @Les its working 50% :) my fault, NOTARY_NAMES is a val NOTARY_NAMES = listOf("Controller", "NetworkService"). Any idea on how to search in all elements?

Comment: @tale - yes, break it down into individual steps, examine the kind of input and output each step is producing.  Also, update your question to indicate that "NOTARY_NAMES is = listOf("Controller", "NetworkService")

Comment: temporarily convert your return statement to
`    return mapOf("getParticipants" to nodeInfo
            .map { it1 -> println(it1); it1.legalIdentities.first().toString() }
            .filter { it2 -> println(it2); it2 != myLegalName && it2 !in NOTARY_NAMES })`
... and see if you are getting what you are expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your stated output, your predicate after substituting for your result values looks like this...

```
"C=GB,L=London,O=UserA" != "UserA" && "C=GB,L=London,O=UserA" !in "Controller"
// or, after using information from your comments
"C=GB,L=London,O=UserA" != "UserA" && "C=GB,L=London,O=UserA" !in listOf("Controller","NetworkSErvice")
```

... and of course neither filters out what you want.

If some other field besides `legalIdentities.first()` contains the information you want, then filter on that (and call filter before map)...

```
.filter { it.someOtherField() != myLegalName &&
          it.someOtherField() !in NOTARY_NAMES } //then...
.map { it.legalIdentities.first().toString() }
```

Otherwise, parse `.legalIdentities.first()` to get the "O" member of the string and filter on that.